# How can we use a IP to get the Geolocation Data using Here API

Tags: here-api

I was looking at the Here Documentation to convert the IP to Geo data but all the links Correspond to having Geo data from Lat and Long is anything am i missing.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to use IP to get geolocation data instead of lat long?

Answer (score 1):

HERE doesn't have a product like IP Geolocation API (get geo-coordinate by only IP-address).

You need to use a third party API for that.(E.g.: commercial http://www.ip2location.com/ or Free http://search.cpan.org/dist/GeoIP2/)

HERE has the product [Positioning API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html)

The HERE Positioning API enables developers to build applications that require location estimates **based on radio network measurement data**. The supported measurement data includes 2G, 3G, 4G, and WLAN measurements.